# Using a list's assigned name from a character string in a vector

Tags: r, list

I have some lists:

```
my_list1 <- list("data" = list(c("a", "b", "c")), "meta" = list(c("a", "b")))
my_list2 <- list("data" = list(c("x", "y", "z")), "meta" = list(c("x", "y")))
```

I'd like to be able to perform some operations on these lists but I need to use the names of the lists stored in a vector as I'm creating them dynamically from an API call. Such a vector might be:

```
list_vec <- c("my_list1", "my_list2")
```

I'm running into problems evaluating the character string in the vector into the name of the list. I know this topic's been covered but the part I'm stuck on specifically is being able to extract just the `data` sublist when running functions within `assign`. Essentially a situation like this:

```
library(purrr)
for(i in seq_along(1:length(list_vec))){
  assign(list_vec[[i]], map_df(list_vec[[i]][["data"]], unlist))
}
```

Which would give a result of:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  data 
  <chr>
1 a    
2 b    
3 c
```

I could also do something like:

```
my_list1$meta <- NULL
```

with

```
list_vec[[1]][["meta"]] <- NULL
```

To reduce the list to just the `data` sublist, but I can't within dynamically assigned names.

I've also wrapping things with `eval` but can't get that to work.

So specifically I need to evaluate the list's name from a string so I can extract a sublist from it.

Comment: Can you show the expected out? BTW there is no need for `seq_along` in `seq_along(1:length(list_vec))`, `1:length(list_vec)` gives the same output.

Comment: If you want to refer to lists like that (and they are similarly purposed), then perhaps you should store them in a single named list to begin with. For example, a single list with `list(my_list1=list("data"=...), my_list2=list("data"=...))`, then you can just work on that single list.

Comment: I meant to use `map_df` instead of `map`. Output would be a df. I'll add to the OP.

Comment: @nycrefugee Is this what you are looking for: `unlist(lapply(mget(list_vec), "[[", "data"), recursive = FALSE)`

Comment: @markus that's exactly it - works. I can adapt to the full example. Thank you. If you include as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can pass the vector `list_vec` to `mget`, which returns a nested list. We use `lapply` to extract (`[[`) the `data` element and use `unlist` to convert this nested list to a list.

```
unlist(lapply(mget(list_vec), `[[`, "data"), recursive = FALSE)
```

Result

```
#$my_list1
#[1] "a" "b" "c"

#$my_list2
#[1] "x" "y" "z"
```

Comment: I did some more research around this after your answer (and re-remembering `[[`is a function) and found `extract2` from `magrittr` worked a charm also.